# Pods Terminating abruptly when Using KEDA with Azure function Queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kubernetes-helm, serverless, keda

I am using KEDA for auto-scaling my ML Workload pods. The pods auto-scales based on the number of queue items, when the queue scales down even when the pods are still processing queue workloads. I have set terminationGracePeriodSeconds but either too high or too low for our workload.

Read about SIGTERM signal and prestop, but could not find any sample that can solve this problem using KEDA queue helm chart

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes we did fix it. Will update the answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

We fixed the issue by increasing the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` in deployment.YAML. This might not be the right fix, but it worked for us. Hope it helps someone who has the same issue.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: test
spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: test
                image: ...
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
```

If you are using the function app, also decrease the batch size, so the pod is not caught up processing for a longer time.

Comment: I have a new case where the function takes at max 10 minutes and the terminationGracePeriodSeconds is 15 minutes. Still sometimes my pods seem to be crashing abruptly. Any suggestions? My batch size is 1 and queueLength is also 1. I have also posted a question for the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902251/terminationgraceperiodseconds-not-working-for-queue-triggered-function

Comment: Check the RAM and CPU size, mostly the problem.

Comment: I have sufficient CPU and RAM.